# Custom ErrorHandler in dropwizard application

Tags: error-handling, jetty, dropwizard, managed-bean

I'm trying to set a custom ErrorHandler in dropwizard 1.0.2

In my Application class in the run method I have the following lines:

```
  environment.getApplicationContext().setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
  environment.getAdminContext().setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
```

However, the code from `CustomErrorHandler` is not called, instead default ErrorHandler class is being used when e.g. I hit a URL that cannot be served.

While debugging the issue, I realize that `ContainerLifeCycle` object contains the following bean: `{org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@375084c9,AUTO}` and does not contain a bean for `CustomErrorHandler`. My guess is that my error handler gets overwritten when default ErroHandler is set later upon application startup.

Any pointers how to set a custom error handler would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to do this is within a server lifecycle listener, e.g.

```
environment.lifecycle().addServerLifecycleListener(new ServerLifecycleListener() {
        @Override
        public void serverStarted(Server server) {
            server.setErrorHandler(new MyCustomErrorHandler());
        }
    });
```